# ASP.NET: how to replace ImageButton with normal text, keeping serverside rules for the button?

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton, ascx

I have an .ascx file (part of an old website; obsolete, messed up and developed years ago from others) with

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lnkAddCart" runat="server" OnCommand="addCart" />
```

The serverside code makes the button visible or not depending on user login and on click adds that specific product to cart. That code section is used for every product in the website.

I want to replace ImageButton tag with a standard button like:

```
<div>
   <a>
      Add to cart
   </a>
</div>
```

I want this new button has the same working serverside code originally applied to ImageButton (like on click THAT product is added to the cart).

I tried using the same ID with

```
<div class="button" id="lnkAddCart" runat="server" OnCommand="addCart">
   Add to cart
</div>
```

but i get only errors.

How can I get to my goal?
Would be better just using the .ascx file or Javascript cause the serverside code in .ascx.CS file is very messed up and probably linked with other files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this button is inside any other control like `Gridview`?

Comment: So a `LinkButton`?

Answer (score 0):

Could make it only with the original .csproj file (didn't have it before).

- Opened the entire project in Visual Studio;
- Created a new asp:LinkButton with new ID, CommandArgument="", and same OnCommand of the asp:ImageButton
- Edited the CS code replacing the old image ID with new button ID everywhere (to keep same rules).
- Deleted the original asp:LinkButton
- Built and replaced all the files.

I couldn't make it editing only .ascx and .ascx.CS file. Visual studio automatically made changes also in other files (like config) and solved my problem.